# Do I have to delete lambdas?

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, function-pointers, destructor

I am storing pointers to lambdas in dynamically allocated objects:

```
struct Function {
    SomeType*(*func)(int);
    Function(SomeType*(*new_func)(int)):
        func(new_func) {}
}

Function* myf = new Function(
    [](int x){ return doSomething(x); }
);

delete myf;
```

Do I have to write something special in the destructor of this class?

Comment: One remark - why not to use `unique_ptr` or `shared_ptr` instead of `new` and `delete`?

Comment: Why do you think that you might have to write something special in the destructor?

Comment: just the fact that something is a pointer, does not mean you need to delete it.

Comment: @David Haim I know, I just wondered who would care for the deletion of the lambda. As I understand it, no one will until the end of the program. Nice.

Comment: Warning: only stateless lambdas can be converted to function pointers. Using `std::function` instead of a raw function pointer would allow any functor having the right parameter and result type.

Comment: @hvd stateless means that they don't capture anything in the `[ ]` field, right? Mine will have fixed type, but thanks for the advice on `std::function`.

Comment: @user6245072 Yes, that's what I meant. For completeness, stateless was probably the wrong word, a lambda that has a general `[&]` or `[=]` capture list but happens to end up not capturing anything, is technically stateless too, but still cannot be converted to a function pointer.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

No, you do not need to do anything special. In this case (you're converting the lambda to a function pointer) this is no different to telling you that you don't need to delete `doSomething` either.

More generally, lambdas are unnamed types with deleted default constructors. This means you can only explicitly create one with new expression by copy/move constructing it - and only then you'd have to call `delete`.

> N4140 §5.1.2 [expr.prim.lambda] /20
>
> The closure type associated with a *lambda-expression* has a deleted
>   default constructor and a deleted copy assignment operator.

Comment: What if I save the lambda object itself, rather than converting it to a function pointer? https://pastebin.com/GJCkKjxY

Answer (score 4):

Without knowing what your class is supposed to do, it is impossible to tell you what its destructor should or shouldn't do.

If the class directly allocates dynamic memory (with `new` or `malloc` [don't use `malloc`]), then you would have to consider how to deallocate that memory. Likewise, if the class acquires other resources such as file pointers, you will have to consider how to release those resources. Typically, the proper place to do that is the destructor.

Ask yourself: Does the class directly allocate any dynamic memory or aquire external resources? Answer appears to be: No, it doesn't. So there appears to not be anything in particular that should be explicitly done in the body of the destructor.